# use select and map with ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary and I would like to select all elements having `vg_name == 'vgapplis'` and calculate the sum of their `size_FS`. I tried this but it does not work. An idea ?

```
- set_fact:
    FS_vgapplis:"{{ FS | select(''search'', ''\bvgapplis\b'')| map(attribute='size_FS')|list|sum }}"
```

This is what my `FS` variable looks like

```
FS:
  - nom_FS: /appm/oracle/product
    nom_LV: lv_product
    size_FS: 5
    owner_FS: oracle
    group_FS: dba
    vg_name: vgapplis

  - nom_FS: /appm/oracle/product/12.1.0.2
    nom_LV: lv_12102
    size_FS: 15
    owner_FS: oracle
    group_FS: dba
    vg_name: vgapplis

  - nom_FS: /apps/oracle/logs
    nom_LV: lvlogs
    size_FS: 5
    owner_FS: oracle
    group_FS: dba
    vg_name: vglogs
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi @pnakache and welcome to SF. `does not work` is nether a good description of your problem in itself. You should always give as much info as possible for others to help you: show the output when running the playbook, describe the result you get compared to the one you expect, if you have any errors, describe what you have done to try to fix them and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [`select` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#select) wrongly with rather weird argument (I suspect a copy/paste error but I'm not sure). `select` will apply a test to each object in the list. I don't know any `search` test that can be applied to a hashmap (The closest I can think of is the python `search` method of an `re` -i.e. regexp- object which would not be appropriate anyway)

In your case, you are looking for a specific value of an attribute of your hashmap. This can be done with the [`selectattr` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#selectattr) which will apply a test to a given attribute of the objects in the list and return only the ones passing the test.

There is a different approach to your problem which is more compact IMO using the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

Below is an example playbook using both approaches leading to the same result.

```
---
- name: Sum size of FS
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    FS:
      - nom_FS: /appm/oracle/product
        nom_LV: lv_product
        size_FS: 5
        owner_FS: oracle
        group_FS: dba
        vg_name: vgapplis

      - nom_FS: /appm/oracle/product/12.1.0.2
        nom_LV: lv_12102
        size_FS: 15
        owner_FS: oracle
        group_FS: dba
        vg_name: vgapplis

      - nom_FS: /apps/oracle/logs
        nom_LV: lvlogs
        size_FS: 5
        owner_FS: oracle
        group_FS: dba
        vg_name: vglogs

  tasks:

    - name: Calculate with selectattr, map and sum
      debug:
        msg: "{{ FS | selectattr('vg_name', 'equalto', 'vgapplis') | map(attribute='size_FS') | list | sum }}"

    - name: Calculate with json_query
      vars:
        sum_query: "[?vg_name=='vgapplis'].size_FS | sum(@)"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ FS | json_query(sum_query) }}"
```

And the result

```
PLAY [Sum size of FS] ****************************************************************

TASK [Calculate with selectattr, map and sum] ****************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "20"
}

TASK [Calculate with json_query] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "20"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I had to replace equalto by match for the compatibility with pre-jinja 2.8